# Como passar o nome da Imagem Dinamicamente?

Tags: java, android, imageview, drawable

Olá, estou aprendendo agora e consegui fazer um aplicativo Cara ou Coroa com Sucesso e resolvi criar outro baseado nele. Esse outro aplicativo aparrtir de um clique no botão da mainActivity ele chama uma segunda activity que exibe aleatoriamente uma imagem das 36 imagens que estão na pasta drawable.
Gostaria de compartilhar e aqui mesmo achei a resposta para fazer essa tarefas, mas ao tentar criar um metodo para compartilhar, me deparei com a seguinte dificuldade: Não sei como passar o nome da imagem dinamicamente pra poder reaproveitar o método para todas as 36 sem ter que reescrever 36 vezes, imagino que seja possível mas não descobri como tratar a informação corretamente. Abaixo o trecho do código a que me refiro:

Eu chamo o metodo checarPermissao aqui:

```
if( extra != null){

if (opcaoEscolhida.equals("s1")){
    imagem.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.s1));
    imagem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                  @Override
                                  public void onClick(View v) {
                                      checarPermissao("s1");
                                  }
                              }
    );
```

OS métodos que achei aqui e adaptei:

```
private void checarPermissao(String img){
    // Verifica  o estado da permissão de WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Se for diferente de PERMISSION_GRANTED, então vamos exibir a tela padrão
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, SOLICITAR_PERMISSAO);
    } else {
        // Senão vamos compartilhar a imagem
        sharedImage(img);
    }
}

private void sharedImage(String img){
    // Vamos carregar a imagem em um bitmap

    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.s1);  //aqui eu queria que recebe cada "sN" das imagens... mas nao sei como fazer...
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    //setamos o tipo da imagem
    share.setType("image/jpeg");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    // comprimomos a imagem
    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    // Gravamos a imagem
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), b, "Sorte de Hoje", null);
    // criamos uam Uri com o endereço que a imagem foi salva
    Uri imageUri =  Uri.parse(path);
    // Setmaos a Uri da imagem
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
    // chama o compartilhamento
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Compartilhe"));
}
```

A solução que funcionou pra fim foi a abaixo, infelizmente repetindo o código, pois não consegui criar um método passando a informação e fiz essa gambiarra, argh...

```
public class SorteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView imagem;
//private ImageView botaoVoltar;
private static final int SOLICITAR_PERMISSAO = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sorte);

    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    imagem = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sorteId);
    //botaoVoltar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.botaoVoltarId);

    Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
    String opcaoEscolhida = extra.getString("opcao");

    if( extra != null){

        if (opcaoEscolhida.equals("s1")){
            imagem.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.s1));
            imagem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                          @Override
                                          public void onClick(View v) {
                                              //checarPermissao();
                                              int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SorteActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                                              if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                                  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SorteActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, SOLICITAR_PERMISSAO);
                                              } else {
                                                  Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.s1);
                                                  Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                                  //setamos o tipo da imagem
                                                  share.setType("image/jpeg");
                                                  ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                                  // comprimomos a imagem
                                                  b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
                                                  // Gravamos a imagem
                                                  String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), b, "Sorte de Hoje", null);
                                                  // criamos uam Uri com o endereço que a imagem foi salva
                                                  Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(path);
                                                  // Setmaos a Uri da imagem
                                                  share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
                                                  // chama o compartilhamento
                                                  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Compartilhe"));
                                              }
                                          }
                                      }
            );
        }else if (opcaoEscolhida.equals("s2")) { ... e assim por diante até o s35... #cruzcredo...
```

Comment: o que significa `s1`?

Comment: é o nome da imagem na pasta drawable. "s1.jpg"

Comment: certo. O que `R.drawable.s1` retorna? Não vejo referência à esse `R`.

Comment: Eu consegui resolver desse jeito, que achei horroroso, mas nao tinha mais tempo pra poder descobrir como passar essa informação dinamicamente, tive que repetir o mesmo código 35 vezes... MAs sou iniciante, conheço os conceitos de herança, mas tenho zero habilidade com a sintaxe e a logica do Java e muitos bloqueios em relação a ele por ser de uma época em que a programação era estruturada, mas to aqui tentando aprender né... rsrs Bom o código que resolveu, caso alguém precise é o abaixo, não repeti todo pra não ficar muito extenso. Eu queria um método... Vou seguir a sugestão do colega abaixo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes fazer uma lista com todos as tuas imagens assim:

```
list.add(R.drawable.s1);
list.add(R.drawable.s2);
list.add(R.drawable.s3);
list.add(R.drawable.s4);
```

para ir buscar os `R.drawable.sN` basta fazeres um `for` que isto trata do problema!

```
for(int i =1; i<36; i++){
     list.get(i);
}
```

Alguma duvida ou algum erro diz :) espero que isto ajude!!

Comment: Perfeito! Foi tentar fazer isso. Obrigada!